# Twitter API: Invalid Content response while uploading video

Tags: video, twitter, ffmpeg

I'm uploding videos to Twitter API via `/1.1/media/upload.json` endpoint. I'm dealing with the following error:

```
{"request":"\/1.1\/media\/upload.json","error":"InvalidContent."}
```

I found the problem/solution in [this Twitter Community question](https://twittercommunity.com/t/uploading-video-chunked-error-on-finalize-command/67035/22) that suggest it's a video codec issue.

These screenshots belongs to 2 videos that i'm trying to upload. But i'm not sure what kind of convertion should i need to apply (using [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) library) to make it work.

[image]

Also, i was reading all the [Twitter recommendations/restrictions](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/media/uploading-media#videorecs) to upload videos, and it seems right

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It could be a video codec issue or it could be a problem with the file size as Twitter only supports video uploads up to 15mb. Therefore you have to use the Chunked Media Upload approach. One way to get a clearer picture of what you may be dealing with, is by attaching the following code to your formData object:

```
media_category: 'tweet_video'
```

This then returned the following JSON response:

```
STATUS:  200 {
"media_id":1166679087613698048,
"media_id_string":"1166679087613698048",
"media_key":"7_1166679087613698048",
"size":1055736,
"processing_info":{
"state":"failed",
"progress_percent":100,
"error":{
"code":3,
"name":"UnsupportedMedia",
"message":"file is currently unsupported" }}}
```

Then I used an npm module called split-file, to split the file so the video can be uploaded in chunks, within Twitter's video upload limit.

Comment: I am getting the same error but the status is saying "in progress", percentage is 99 however the check_after_secs is 0. Code is also 3 the video is 815K

Comment: @Nulik same, stuck at 99% progress and check_after_secs is 0

Comment: @PGT I had to resample my video to 640x480 and it worked (I used ffmpeg library)

Comment: @Nulik same, I was also able to get it working with a quick ffmpeg mp4 to mp4 conversion (no output parameters were set). I think originally my video didn't have a lot of metadata or some things were off, the conversion helped to standardize it